# Url sent as parameter to $.ajax() function is not being used for handling the POST request

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, ajaxform

I'm trying to submit this form. I have other fields where I'm using ajax call for auto-sugestion. Before adding the below code, auto-suggestion works fine. But when I add the below code, aut-sugestion does not work.

When I remove the code inside $.ajax() function, auto-sugestion works fine. And with this code, if I try to submit the form it does the POST request but url is localhost:8000 not the one I have provided as parameter in $.ajax() function. Also, when I try to look into the django shell for data, nothing is saved. I tried everything that I could.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#info-form', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // this prevents from refreshing the page

    $.ajax(
            url: '/create/new/', //ajax call will be made to this url
            type: 'post',
            data:{
                date:$('#tentative-date').val(),
                time:$('#tentative-time').val(),
                is_better:$('#is-better').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },
            success: function(){
                alert("Successful!");
            }
        );
});
```

Comment: You left off the `{}` around the arguments given to `ajax()`.   `$.ajax({ url: '', type: '', ... })` This is a typo question.

Comment: Thanks.. it solved the problem.. so silly I'm :(